# Personal OneDrive, OneDrive for Businesses and LiveSDK

Tags: windows-phone, office365api, live-sdk

I have developed a Windows Phone 8 app using the LiveSDK API to access files in OneDrive. It works fine using the personal OneDrive. Now my customer have installed OneDrive for Businesses and cannot log in. Do I have to use another API to reach OneDrive for Businesses? If so, is this API available for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1):

The LiveSDK does not support logging into OneDrive for business accounts.  Microsoft does not yet have a public SDK for windows phone that will allow for interaction with OneDrive consumer and OneDrive for business services.

Answer (score 0):

To access OneDrive for Business, you can use Office 365 APIs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations
You will have to create and Office 365 developer account, and set up and Azure Active Directory tenant.
OneDrive for Business uses a different API than the Live SDK. 
Hope this helps!